# Find bases and dimensions of the following subspaces:

Tags: linear-algebra

Find bases and dimensions of the following subspaces:

$\{(x, y, z) | x = y + 2z\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Same context, different question about the context.  In this, it is already assumed that the student knows that it is a subspace and is being asked about further details about it.  In the linked question, that assumption is what is being asked to be proven.

Comment: How many linearly independent vectors are needed to form a basis for that subspace? (I might add that as a linear system, you should be able to find particularly simple answers. This is a basic question; you just need to understand the definition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = y + 2z\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x=\alpha+2\beta\\y=\alpha\\z=\beta \end{cases}\;(\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R})$$ $$\Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}{x}\\{y}\\{z}\end{pmatrix}=\alpha\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{1}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}}_{v_1}+\beta\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{2}\\{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}}_{v_2}\;(\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}).$$ $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$ spans the given subspace and is clearly linearly independent so, $B$ is also a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Well it has dimension $2$ since it has two free variables. Do you know how to go about constructing a basis for a space? Where in that do you get confused?

Comment: {(x, y, z) | (y+2z, y, z) } and now i can see that that this vector can be done i terms of two variables ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
 The linear map 
\begin{align}
f\colon \mathbf R^2&\longrightarrow \mathbf R^3 \\
(y,z)&\longmapsto (y+2z, y,z)
\end{align}
induces an isomorphism from  $\mathbf R^2$ onto the mentioned subspace.

Comment: y[1,1,0]
z[2,0,1] is the base ?

Comment: Almost. What do $y$ and $z$ do here? B. t. w., welcome to TeX SX!

Comment: respresents the vector z and y ?

Comment: $z$ and $y$ are scalars, not vectors. You're almost at it!

Comment: Ok guy i think it will be right that,

You firstly have to make an basis which is constructed from y+2z,y,z 

so span {v1,v2} = {x,y,z | x=y+2z}

q1v1+q2v2=0 is in V=(0,0,0)
then (q1,q1,0)(2q2,0,q2)
q1+2q2=0
q1=0
q2=0

Anybody else, what can i do more? Is it good explenation?

Comment: But what is the proposed basis?

Comment: [0 1 0] [0 0 1] ?

Comment: No. Rewrite $(y+2z,y,z)$ as $y(?,?,?)+z(?, ?,?)$.

Comment: y(1,1,0) + z(2,0,1) ?

Comment: Yes. So what's the basis?

Comment: So what exactly is a base.

Comment: A family of vectors such that  every vector in the (sub)space is a unique linear combination of the vectors in the family. Note that an isomorphism maps a basis of the domain to a basis of the image.

Comment: How am i suposed to find it?  Isn't [1.1.0] and [2.0.1] unique?

Comment: $\{(1,1,0),(2,0,1)\} $  *is* the seeked basis (it is the image of the basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ of $\mathbf R^2$).

Comment: {(1,0.0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)} of R^3 ?

Comment: Did you read my previous comment?

Comment: span (1,1,0) and span(2,0,1) ?

Comment: A span is not a basis, it's a subspace.

Comment: v1 [1,1,0]
v2 [2,0,1] ?

Comment: If you mean v1=…, v2=…, yes.